# Pre-Post analysis with repeated measure

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, sas, pre-post-comparison

I've 50 subjects and ran an experiment 4 times for each subject and collected the pre and post values for each run. I need to do pre-post analysis. Here a **sample** of my data:

```
**ID  experiement   PrePost Value**
  1         1        pre    1.2
  1         2        post   5.8
  1         3        post   4.6
  1         4        pre    2.7
....
  2         1        pre    3.2
  2         2       post    7.9
  2         3       pre     3.5
  2         4       post    6.6
....
  3         1       pre     5.1
  3         2       post    4.8
  3         3       pre     5.7
  3         4       post    2.5
```

How can I do this in SAS and check for the normality assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
data a1;
set a;
la1= log(value);     


proc sort data = a1;
by id experiement PrePost ;
run; 

ods html;
ods graphics on;

proc mixed data=a1 order=data;
      class id experiement PrePost ;
      model la1 =   experiement PrePost /solution s residual;
      repeated / type=cs subject=id;
   run;
ods graphics off;
ods html close;
```